# How to show list of users with specific status in Yii php?

Tags: php, database, yii

Hello I have users with different status on my website, I have a field in database table called `user_status`. Im displaying only one type of user in my report list of users, but i want to display two type of users..

Currently it is only displaying users who are `fired` means their status is fired. but i want to display users who are fired and also on probation period in same list.

This is what im doing right now but it is only showing users who are fired..

`$model->MYUSER_STATUS = 'Fired';`

i want to show both user list who are fired and on probation period..

1. Fired (15 users are Fired)
2. Probation (45 users are on probation)

Currently it is only showing 15 fired users, but i want to display all 60 users (45+15). I have tried this so far, but its NOT working,

```
$model->MYUSER_STATUS = 'Fired' && $model->MYUSER_STATUS = 'Probation';
```

Here is my Model code..

```
class Users extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $MYUSER_STATUS;

    public function searchUsers()
    {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $this->status = $this->MYUSER_STATUS;

    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name);
    $criteria->compare('date_of_birth',$this->date_of_birth,true);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>false,
    ));
}
```

My controller..

```
public function actionUserList(){
    $this->layout = 'cgridlisting';
    $model=new Users('searchUsers');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

    $model->MYUSER_STATUS = 'Fired';

    if(isset($_GET['Users']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Users'];

    if(isset($_GET['Users']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Users'];

    $this->render('users_list',array(
        'model'=>$model
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this way first create array of user status which status of user you want to display. like i have crated below.

```
$userStatus =  array('0'=>'Fired','1'=>'Probation');
```

then add below line of code in searchUsers function for  criteria

```
$criteria->addInCondition('status', $userStatus );
```

add above line in searchUsers function may this will helps you.

Comment: Where should i create this array first? In model ?

Comment: can you edit my code and show me where should i replace ur code

Comment: Yes in model inside the searchUsers function.